# Nginx access log problems

Tags: email, nginx, digital-ocean, mezzanine

I followed a course on skillshare where the instructor went over how to create a blog using the Mezzanine CMS for Django. I have my blog deployed on DigitalOcean.

I have issues when trying to use my contact form. I have looked into my `access.log` file to see what was wrong, but found that `nginx` only returns a 500 status code, and nothing else. So, I can't troubleshoot any further.

My question is how can I get a more verbose error message? I want to know if my password isn't working, or if the email host isn't correct. I am using `smtp.gmail.com` as the host in my settings. At the moment, I can't tell  what exactly is wrong with my configuration. I've looked into many posts, and have tried multiple things. I am sort of lost at the moment, because I want to get my contact page working.

Comment: Look at the nginx error log, not the access log. Add corresponding messages from that log to your question.

Comment: I just see `signal process started` a few times, and nothing else. I guess Nginx isn't finding an error?

Comment: If it is nginx who returns a 500 error, there should be some corresponding line in its error log.

Comment: How can I find out if nginx returned the 500 error? I just went into nginx's access log and found that it returned a 500 code when using my contact form. Although, it didn't state what returned the 500 code.